# Change the color of a Button using color numerical values

Tags: android, colors

I change the color of button in this way:

```
final Button BB1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
               BB1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

How can I change to the color `#FF6600`?

Comment: Please ask one question per post. For your second unrelated question, ask a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
final Button BB1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
BB1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6600"));
```

For spinner selection,

Have you tried `spinner.setSelection(14);` ? (14 or 15, pass index what you need at start time)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use as below.

```
BB1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0xff, 0x66, 0x00));
```

Answer (score 0):

A more "separation of concerns" type of solution is to add the color to strings.xml

```
<color name="button_background">#f60</color>
```

Reference is in code by it's id (linked via R.java):

```
BB1.setBackgroundColor(R.color.button_background);
```

This solution makes even more sense if you have more widgets with the same color.

Btw, consider using camel case to name your variables, i.e name the button object bb1 (or bB1 if you must :-) ) instead of BB1.